# Spark - Zeppelin - Docker - Can not access to MySQL with jdbc

Tags: docker, apache-spark, mysql-connector, apache-zeppelin

I am tryng to connect to MySQL with Spark and Zeppelin using Docker.
Some docker-yaml file settup:

```
zeppelin:
    image: apache/zeppelin:0.9.0
    container_name: zeppelin
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/notebook:/notebook
      - ${PWD}/logs:/logs
      - ${PWD}/data:/learn
      - ${PWD}/spark/conf:/spark/conf
      - ${PWD}/spark/jars:/spark/user_jars
      - ${PWD}/spark/sql/:/spark/sql/
    environment:
      - SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS=--packages=org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.7.2 --jars=/spark/user_jars/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar
      - ZEPPELIN_LOG_DIR=/logs
      - ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_DIR=/notebook
      - ZEPPELIN_ADDR=0.0.0.0
      - ZEPPELIN_SPARK_MAXRESULT=10000
      - ZEPPELIN_INTERPRETER_OUTPUT_LIMIT=204800
      - ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_COLLABORATIVE_MODE_ENABLE=false
```

And this is env when i exec to container:

```
LOG_TAG=[ZEPPELIN_0.9.0]:
Z_VERSION=0.9.0
HOSTNAME=zeppelin
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
ZEPPELIN_LOG_DIR=/logs
PWD=/opt/zeppelin
SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS=--packages=org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.7.2 --jars=/spark/user_jars/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar
ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_DIR=/notebook
HOME=/opt/zeppelin
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
TERM=xterm
ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_COLLABORATIVE_MODE_ENABLE=false
SHLVL=1
ZEPPELIN_ADDR=0.0.0.0
ZEPPELIN_INTERPRETER_OUTPUT_LIMIT=204800
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
Z_HOME=/opt/zeppelin
ZEPPELIN_SPARK_MAXRESULT=10000
PATH=/opt/conda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
_=/usr/bin/env
```

But when i try to access to MySQL, with scala code as below

```
val jdbcDriver = spark.conf.get("spark.jdbc.driver.class", "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")
val dbHost = spark.conf.get("spark.jdbc.host","mysql")
val dbPort     = spark.conf.get("spark.jdbc.port", "3306")
val defaultDb  = spark.conf.get("spark.jdbc.default.db", "default")
val dbTable    = spark.conf.get("spark.jdbc.table", "customers")
val dbUser     = spark.conf.get("spark.jdbc.user", "root")
val dbPass     = spark.conf.get("spark.jdbc.password", "dataengineering")

val connectionUrl = s"jdbc:mysql://$dbHost:$dbPort/$defaultDb"
```

I get error about org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
  at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:62)
```

I don't know what wrong with this setup and code above ? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` instead of `org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver`.

Also, in zeppelin, in the INTERPRETER MENU, find the spark interpreter, click the EDIT button and add the artifact `mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.11`